# Angular2 Routing not working in IIS

Tags: angular, iis, angular2-routing

I hosted my Angular2 application in IIS, I have three components in my application.
The first component is loading perfect, but remaining components are not loading properly.
My Application launching URL is

> http://localhost/UI/login/

(loading assets properly). When I am routing to another component on a button click I am referring the same Image which is located in assets folder, which is not loading properly.
I found the root cause for it, but I don't know how to solve it. The reason is 
on button click it will redirect to

> localhost/UI/log/Project02 (I could not add https:// as it is not allowing more than 2 links)

and localhost(in server) is looking the assets folder like this **localhost/UI/log/assets/logo.png** instead of **localhost/UI/assets/logo.png**. The same image is loaded in first component but not in second component why? I tried by changing **base href="/"** in index.html also.

My second problem is, On a button click I am routing to 3rd component it is taking as localhost/UI/log/logdetails/2 instead of localhost/UI/logdetails/2

Can anyone help me on this?

This is Html code for referring the logo

> ```
>   <a href="#"><img src="assets/logo.png" alt=""></a> <span class="header-txt">Log</span>
> ```

and [this is my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUw46.png)

Comment: please provide your code where you have added the image

Comment: @Faisal: I updated my question, please check it

Comment: change your img to this: `<img src="/UI/assets/logo.png" alt="">`

Comment: @Faisal: I am getting errors in imports also for example I referred my service as import { LogSearchService } from '../shared/log-search.service'; which is not working.

Comment: Change it to './../shared/log-search.service'

Comment: @Faisal: On a button click I am routing to 3rd component it is taking as http://localhost/UI/log/logdetails/2 instead of http://localhost/UI/logdetails/2

And also the UI is the name of the folder in my hosted site. If I want to host in another server with name LogViewerUI I want to change my code again, which is not recommended.

Comment: you are posting different questions in your comments, makes no sense.

Comment: the UI is the name of the folder in my hosted site. If I want to host in another server with name LogViewerUI I want to change my code again, which is not recommended. 

Sorry for my another question in comment

Comment: then change the img to `<img src="../assets/logo.png" alt="">` in the second component.

Comment: The same html code which I mentioned is working in login component, but not in log. Can I know the reason please?

Comment: because login is your launching url

Comment: @Faisal: I changed both import and image src as you suggested. It is not working for me

Comment: i would suggest you to do a `ng build` then point that folder to IIS it should work

Comment: I solved my loading image issue. But, I could not solve the routing issue i.e routing to localhost/UI/log/logdetails/2 instead of localhost/UI/logdetails/2.
@Rahul: I did the same,  it is not working

Answer (score 1):

I modified my code to:

```
img src="../assets/logo.png" alt=""
```

Which loaded my image properly.

By default base URL is set as (/) or root.

This means that your app would start from root folder i.e. locally it would consider localhost:1234/ and on server it would consider root folder.

When you run your app, it may confuse your browser as your files are not at root path and could through 404.

So best way is to add relative path in base href like:

```
<base href=”/Project_Name/”>
```